# Calculating browser text layout

Tags: java, javascript, css, gwt

I want to determine ahead of time how the browser will wrap words on a panel. I'm assuming if I know the width in pixels for each word as it displays on a given panel, and the width of the panel, I can calculate how many words will display on a specific line.

I have an array of words. For each word, I first obtain the pixel width (GWT):

```
storeWidths(HorizontalPanel hp)   {
for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) {
Label l = new Label(words.get(i));
hp.add(l);
Integer width = hp.getOffsetWidth();
wordWidths.add(width);
hp.remove(l);
}
```

This function seems to be working as I am getting reasonable values. Note the passed-in HorizontalPanel has already been styled and added to the the Root panel.

Having the pixel width of each word (and space), I then try to determine how many words fit on a given line.

The display panel is 306 pixels wide.

The below data shows one line of calculation.  The 1st column is the number of horizontal pixels available, starting with 306.  The 2nd column is the width of the word in pixels. The 3rd column is the actual word.  According to this I should be able to fit words "One" through "nine" on a single line before running out of horizontal space:

- 306   56      1One
- 250   24      two
- 226   33      three
- 193   26      four
- 167   25      five
- 142   21      six
- 121   39      seven
- 82    32      eight
- 50    28      nine

(Note that I am adding the text to an HTML object that has the same style as the panel used by my storeWidths() function above.  The first word has a 25px indent, which is included within the 56 pixels.  )

My problem is that words displayed by the browser are consuming more pixels than what I've calculated. The browser only displays "One" through "seven" in the HTML panel.  There must be some other factor to the browser's word wrap algorithm that I'm not aware of. What I need is a dependable algorithm for determining where words will wrap in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep adding words one by one to a hidden FlowPanel. Once the height of the panel changes, the last word did not fit.

Comment: This general approach is working for me. Simple and sweet. Thanks!